# 403 Forbidden Error setting up Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost

I've run into this problem on other servers before, but this time I can't figure it out. I've tried looking at all the solutions on Stack Overflow, but no luck so far.

---

**The Error**: domain1 works just fine, but trying to access the index on domain2 fails.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

---

**My httpd.conf**

Note: domain1 is a symfony site, so the web root is /web, where as domain2 is just a static html site.

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain1.com/web"
<Directory "/var/www/html/domain1.com/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jason@domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ErrorLog logs/domain2.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain2.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/domain2.com">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

**ls -l in /var/www/html**

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jan 12 17:06 domain2.com
drwxr-xr-x 8 apache apache 4096 Jan 12 15:58 domain1.com
```

---

**Other**

- I've already tried disabling selinux with "setenforce 0"
- I've made sure to restart apache each time after changing httpd.conf by running "service httpd restart"
- I've rebooted the server itself
- Apache Version: 2.2.15
- CentOS Version: 6.5

Comment: Your directory and documentroot lines use `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` but the `ls` output seems to show `domain1` and `domain2`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. I was just replacing them by hand. let me fix that